# When 'I' is used as a subject, why do we disuse 'I' and so create an illusion?

Tags: wittgenstein, self

<sub>Caution: I probably quoted overmuch; please feel free to omit the first few paragraphs and advise what can be omitted.

Source: pp 137-138 , *Think: A Compelling Introduction to Philosophy* (1 ed, 1999) by Simon Blackburn</sub>

> Kant puts this point by talking of the "I think" that accompanies all my representations.
>   In other words, my experiences come billed as "mine". I do not first become acquainted
>   with the experience, then look round for the owner, and then (provided, against Hume,
>   that this last search is successful) announce that the experience is one of mine. Rather,
>   for me to feel a pain is in and of itself to be aware that I am in pain.
>     But how is this possible, if Hume is right that we are never aware of a "self"? It is all
>   very well comparing pains to dents, and it is certainly true that when I am aware of a
>   dent this is only because I am aware of a dented surface. But at least we are aware of
>   surfaces, dented or not. Whereas if Hume is right we do not seem to be aware of our soul
>   or self.
>     Perhaps the way forward has to be to deny that the "self" is the kind of thing of which
>   awareness is possible. Wittgenstein talks of cases where we describe ourselves as
>   subjects of experience: "I hear the rain" or "I have a toothache". He points out that in this
>   kind of case "there is no question of recognizing a person". "It is as impossible that in making the statement 'I have a toothache' I should have mistaken another person for
>   myself, as it is to moan with pain by mistake, having mistaken someone else for me."
>   You cannot misidentify the subject as yourself. Wittgenstein thinks this gives rise to an
>   illusion:
>
> > We feel then that in the cases in which "I" is used as subject, **[1.]** we don't use it because we
> >     recognize a particular person by his bodily characteristics; and **[2.]** this creates the illusion that we
> >     use this word to refer to something bodiless, which, however, has its seat in our body. In fact this
> >     seems to be the real ego, the one of which it was said, "Cogito ergo sum". "Is there then no mind,
> >     but only a body?" Answer: the word "mind" has meaning, i.e., it has a use in our language; but
> >     saying this doesn't yet say what kind of use we make of it.
>
> We should try thinking of self-consciousness some other way. What way?

3. How do we disuse 'I', when 'I' concerns a subject? What does  Wittgenstein mean by  **[1]**?
4. How does **[1]** create the illusion implied by **[2]**?

Answer (score 1):

By **[1]**, he is distinguishing first-person experience from third-person experience. We don't observe ourselves (as a "particular person") having experiences, we just have experiences directly. He is claiming that by allowing the corresponding linguistic move ("I" as a subject), we can dis-identify ourselves from any attempt to locate the subject (me) within the material of the body: "I have a toothache", in common vernacular, means there is something outside of the tooth and the ache which is "me". Likewise with "I have a brain" and "I have a body". If allowed to be interpreted strictly, they entail the subject, "I", to be a bodiless entity of some sort.

But the same move can be done with even non-physical attempts to locate the subject as well. "I *have* an ego, therefore *I* am not ego", "I *have* a soul, therefore *I* am not a soul". I am not sure why the supposed conundrum cannot be resolved by requiring the less-strict interpretation: "'You' may be none of those things individually, but put them all together (and invoke 'emergent phenomena' if necessary), and ... there you are!" (Maybe.)

Comment: re the brain: 3P pronouns are not stored ('him' = 'the male' ...), but 1P and 2P pronouns have actual neural counterparts.  2P is changeable: 'you are Jeff' (you be one Jeff); I store thoughts about you under the topic 'Jeff', because soon 'you' will mean someone else.  1P doesn't change: 'I am John' (me be one John) is stored, but my intentions are stored under 'me', not 'John'.

Comment: Thanks. Does your answer explain my question 4 too?